# Open SSH port a bad idea on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: networking, ssh, security, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a Raspberry Pi at home that I have connected to my home network. I use it to run a VPN server, SSH tunnel, and occasionally I SSH into it to perform maintenance on it.

Is it a bad idea to have ports opened (TCP) on my router so I can remotely connect to my Pi while I'm away from home? I do not use the usual port 22; it is a random port I chose. However, when I scan my IP address using `nmap` on `pentest-tools.com`, I see the open port I chose to use for SSH. My Pi is password-protected, and there is no sensitive data or credit card numbers on my it that I know of. But considering I use it for VPN or SSH tunneling, sensitive data may travel through it. So is it bad to have this SSH port open on my router? Can anyone do anything malicious to my home network by having this port opened, considering my Pi is always on and listening to that port?

Comment: You should disable any services you don't plan to use.  If you have a need for those services, they should be enabled, then take the required steps to harden the security of the OS.

Answer (score 5):

In terms of security, three additional methods come to my mind.

## A: use public key authentication

To add to security, you can set up your SSH server to use public key authentication. That is, either additionally to or instead of a strong password, the connection will be opened only if the SSH client provides the private key which matches the public key on the server. Even if an attacker could gain the public key somehow, he could not recover the private key from that.
However, this will not hide your port from port scanners.

## B: use a different port

Furthermore, I made good experience in terms of less port scans with configuring the SSH server to listen to a different port than 22.
The corresponding, default configuration option in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is

```
Port 22
```

You could change that to, say 54322:

```
Port 54322
```

Remember to re-start the SSH server afterwards; depending on the Linux on your Raspberry, it might be one of

```
# service sshd restart
# systemctl restart sshd
```

(The `#` sign, if not in a file, shall denote a root prompt here in my examples.)

Don't worry, your current SSH session will stay active. It might be worth a try to open a second SSH session to port 54322 to see if login still works.
Remember to

- set your SSH client to the new port
- if applicable, forward the new port in your internet router to the Raspberry Pi

## C: close the port and open it only upon your request

If you really do not want to show "the internet" that you have this port open, have a look at port knocking daemons, e. g. `knockd`. Those programs listen to (closed) ports defined by you, and upon a knocking sequence, also defined by you, open a different port, e. g. your SSH port. 
From a mobile phone or a laptop, you initiate the knocking sequence, and the knock daemon on your Raspberry Pi opens your SSH port, which was not visible at all.

In more detail, port knocking will add a line to your `iptables` configuration. This line will open up the port on your Raspberry. This also means, that the SSH port must be closed by `iptables` before. And this means you cannot login via SSH.

An example `knockd.conf` could look like that:

```
[openclosessh]
    sequence    = 1000,2020,3015,65432
    seq_timeout = 15
    tcpflags    = syn
    start_command   = /usr/local/bin/knockd-open.sh %IP%
    cmd_timeout = 30
    stop_command    = /usr/local/bin/knockd-close.sh %IP%
```

Also, remember to forward the to-be-knocked ports from your internet router to your Raspberry.

The corresponding open/close scripts could look like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
# /usr/local/bin/knockd-open.sh
# adds two lines at the top of iptables which allow all incoming and outgoing traffic on tcp port 54322
iptables -I INPUT -s $1 -p tcp --dport 54322 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -d $1 -p tcp --sport 54322 -j ACCEPT
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
# /usr/local/bin/knockd-close.sh
# deletes those two lines again
iptables -D INPUT -s $1 -p tcp --dport 54322 -j ACCEPT
iptables -D OUTPUT -d $1 -p tcp --sport 54322 -j ACCEPT
```

Remember to make both scripts executable with `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/knockd*`. Also, you should start and enable the knockd service with one of

```
# service knockd start && update-rc.d knockd enable
# systemctl start knockd && systemctl enable knockd
```

Especially if you employ knocking on a remote computer to which you do not have console access, you might want to use `atd` to automatically revoke any changes and/or reboot the Raspberry in case of configuration mistakes.

Because iptables will not be stored across reboots automatically, in an example, you could be root (via `su`) and

```
# at now + 5 minutes
> reboot
> (hit ctrl-d)
# ./script-which-closes-iptables.sh
```

An example `./script-which-closes-iptables.sh` could look like that (remember to make it executable with `chmod +x`)

```
#!/bin/bash
# allow everything on the loopback interface
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# allow only related or established incoming ssh sessions
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 54322 -j ACCEPT
# allow outgoing related or established ssh sessions
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --sport 54322 -j ACCEPT
# allow everything on the loopback interface
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
# drop everything else in and out
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

If your SSH session is dying now, the Raspberry will reboot in 5 minutes. If your SSH session is still active, then revoke the pending reboot with

```
# atq
15 reboot
# atrm 15
```

If your SSH session is still active, try to login via a second SSH session. That should not work. Then use your mobile phone and knock the ports you configured in `/etc/knockd.conf`. After that, try again to login via a second SSH session. This time, it should work.

Then you can make your iptables persist a reboot. On your system, you might have to install a package via

```
# apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

Save your iptables with

```
# iptables-save > /etc/iptables/iptables-rules
```

and enable the iptables service with

```
# systemctl enable iptables
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Raspberry Pi has a strong password and strong SSH security, you're fine; attackers can't do anything with SSH if they can't log into it or exploit it. They will find the port for sure, though.

Historical note: In the past, [there has been a problem](http://siliconangle.com/blog/2015/11/30/ssh-generation-fault-leaves-raspberry-pi-vulnerable-to-hacking/) with the SSH configuration; the auto-generated key was predictable. That's been fixed.

If attackers *do* manage to gain SSH access, they effectively own the device. Then they can use it to do bad things like [ARP Poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing), which allows them to capture and change unencrypted data crossing your network. They could also use the Pi as a launching point for attacks on your other hosts. The Pi is a computer like any other, and you need to be careful to secure it.