# Incoming connections from public to private IP address

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, dd-wrt, private-network

Today i have checked the auth.log of my raspberry (private IP address in my home network behind a wrt54gl). Surprisingly i saw a lot of "Failed password for root from" lines.

The SRC IP can be found on lists of SSH brute force attackers.

When i connect to my raspberry over the internet i usually establish a ssh connection to my routers public IP address and connect to the the raspberry private address.

So how can someone connect directly to this device that only has a private address?

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse b8:27:eb:e5:7a:5b
      inet Adresse:192.168.0.5  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
      RX packets:2774178 errors:0 dropped:933 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:5544091 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenl▒nge:1000
      RX bytes:457172801 (435.9 MiB)  TX bytes:875979564 (835.3 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife
      inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
      RX packets:2695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenl▒nge:0
      RX bytes:725188 (708.1 KiB)  TX bytes:725188 (708.1 KiB)


Jun 15 13:42:12 rpi sshd[15608]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=116.31.116.31  user=root
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you do it, assuming you use port forwarding.
If you try to login to your raspberry from remote, maybe even with a false password, you should see a very similar line in auth.log.

Of course, you will connect to your public IP address which is assigned to the external interface of the router. I assume that you established port forwarding in the router, so that any connect to a specific port on your public IP address will be forwarded to the raspberry. In this specific case, I assume you forwarded port 22 in the router to be forwarded to port 22 of your raspberry.

The way the guy behind the other IP address went is the same and probably like

- scanning the internet for hosts which have ports open
- running a tool which

  - connects to that host and port
  - tries to login with password lists

Or maybe he does it manually and fires up his ssh client, connects to your public IP address, port 22, which will be forwarded to the raspberry, and simply tries common username/password combinations (pi/raspberry, root/root, ...).

To avoid that you can

- configure sshd to use private/public key authentication, not password authentication
- tell your router to forward a different port (e. g. 2222) to port 22 of the raspberry. Be sure to adjust your (remote) ssh client so that you can still connect.
- install `knockd` and knock the port open before you want to use it
- install `fail2ban` to block unauthorized IP addresses

(for a little more detailed overview of the mentioned methods please also see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1065898/open-ssh-port-a-bad-idea-on-a-raspberry-pi/1081988#1081988).)

Comment: Or if you are always tunneling thru your router, disable the port forwarding to your Raspberry Pi :)

Comment: You are absolutely right! There was a port forwarding that I haven't used for some time and forgot about it as i'm always tunneling. My mistake. Thanks for the good explanation.

Comment: You are very welcome.