# iptables allow only ssh,VPN and block scanners

Tags: iptables

i do have a debian VPS that i need to protect. I would like the server to have only access through ssh and openvpn. once connected then no restrictions apply. Also, block scanners and ping to the server. Since i am stuck with the set of iptables commands i would like some help, please. At the moment the iptables are:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

once connected then be able to browse the Internet. Also i would like the system to be able to send emails, dns requests.

Answer (score 2):

Most of your requirements are clear, e. g.:

- the Debian VPS must be able to send emails
- the Debian VPS must be able to query DNS servers
- block scanners from the Debian VPS
- your computer must be able to establish SSH sessions to the VPS
- your computer must be able to establish openVPN sessions to the VPS

Unclear to me is "once connected then be able to browse the Internet". I have an assumption, though. ;)

### send emails

Depending on which protocol you want to use to send emails, open the respective port (e. g. TCP port 25 or TCP port 587; I'll use 25 in the below example):

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

Then, you need to allow incoming return traffic from the remote mail server:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

or better:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED --sport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

(allowing all tcp return traffic from port 25 in a connection established by your Debian VPS).

### DNS queries

This is very similar to sending emails:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

### SSH and openVPN

this is what you already configured yourself

### browse the Internet

I assume that you want to

- connect to the Debian VPS via openVPN
- browse the Internet via the Debian VPS
- so that your PC at home appears as it was the Debian VPS (in terms of public IP address)

So you want to

#### enable kernel forwarding on the Debian VPS:

`$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

and additionally

`$ sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`

and ensure that there is an uncommented (without `#` in front) line which reads

`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

#### enable iptables forwarding

Also, you want to enable forwarding in iptables:
I assume that you use openVPN in routing mode using a `tun` device (as opposed to bridging mode using a `tap` device, and that you use 10.8.0.0/24 (openVPN's default) as IP address range.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i tun+ -s 10.8.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

### blocking scanners

Well, scanners usually look at frequently used ports like 80, 22, 1194. So I personally like to use different ports. I wrote about using different methods [in this superuser post here](https://superuser.com/a/1081988/598797), using `atd` to help you not lock yourself out of the remote Debian VPS. In short, you could

- use SSH and openVPN each on a different port
- use port knocking to open the ports upon request

Comment: Did that help you, @john?