# How to set up a VPS server to allow access from the ouside only by VPN

Tags: vpn, firewall, iptables, setup, vps

I am not sure that my title is clear enough, so I will try to explain what I would like to reach :

I would like to be able to access a VPS server running services (as a private wiki, a private forum and some private websites) only by a VPN access (so a restricted access). I don't want my services to be accessible by anyone other than the VPN users.

But I want to let the VPS the ability to access the web by himself : a script runnning on the VPS should be able to get informations on the web.

What are the solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the VPS built on cPanel, Plesk, something else?

In general, if an "all in one" solution, you would set the VPN client feature on the VPS to send DNS settings to the VPN client user.  The DNS would be your VPS server, so that hits for www.some_thing_on_VPS.com would perform the dns resolution on the box, and send the box's private ip through the VPN to the VPN Client.

Comment: @TG2 It's possible for me to get Plesk 12 CentOS / Plesk 12 Ubuntu / Cpanel 11 or Cozy (Debian 8). The VPS seller says that Cozy( Debian8) is free, so I guess it's the more interesting solution?

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
# for ssh access, in case you want to manage your VPS via ssh
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --sport 22 -j ACCEPT

# for openvpn
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED --sport 1194 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT

# for web
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Be sure to adjust interface names and port numbers. Also, see C) from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1081988/598797) as an example on how not to lock out of your VPS.

Comment: Stueja, your commands will only set up the firewall to allow incoming connections for those ports, it doesn't cover VPN, and in most cases with cPanel or Plesk, they don't use a default IPTables firewall installation and so hand editing usually doesn't work well.

Comment: @TG2. the "# for openvpn" part seems to cover VPN,no?